# trocar comandos no shell

Tags: python, shell, shell-script

O comando

```
python foo.py
```

Quando chamado no terminal, roda o arquivo python enviado. Imagine que eu tenho um arquivo python que sempre precisa ser chamado da seguinte forma:

```
xvfb-run python foo.py
```

para funcionar.

Existe alguma maneira de eu escrever algo do tipo no Shell:

```
python = xvfb-run python
```

Assim, sempre que eu chamar `python` ele vai chamar `xvfb-run python`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se você pode atribuir algo a palavra `python`, em específico. Ela deve estar atrelada aos binários do python e deve ser meio complicado mudar. O que eu sei é que você pode criar um `alias` pro seu comando, algo como

```
$ alias meu_comando = 'xvfb-run python'
```

O uso seria `$ meu_comando foo.py` . Leia sobre `alias` [aqui](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ualias.htm)

**EDIT:**

De acordo com [este](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html) link:

> An alias can be created with the same name as the core name of a command (i.e., a command without any options or arguments). In such case, it is the alias that is called (i.e., activated) first when the name is used, rather than the command with the same name.

Portanto, você pode fazer o que você quer. Só não sei se é uma boa idéia...

Answer (score 1):

Um alias resolveria seu problema, mas caso não resolva desenvolva outro arquivo python que chame a seguencia que você precisa.

bar.py

`import subprocess
subprocess.call("xvfb-run python foo.py")`

Depois chame seu arquivo com o comando criado

`$python bar.py`

Mas reforço que o Alias seria uma alternativa melhor.

Comment: Eu gostava bastante de usar o commands porém foi descontinuado. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html para o python 3

`
import commands
result = commands.getstatusoutput("xvfb-run python foo.py")

`